# Perform POST Request from a Controller in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, e-commerce

I need to integrate a virtual POS (Point of Sale) with my eCommerce website made in Symfony2.

The system is simple: the client has to perform a POST request to a given URL, with few parameters; then from my website the client will be redirected to the bank POS page where he/she can pay the orders.

The problem is that I don't want to send to the client any of the POST parameters in the HTML (because they are sensitive: passwords and signatures), so I am wondering how to achieve that in my Symfony2 environment.

Comment: use cURL to make the post request

Comment: @svprdga Are you referring to POS `(point of Sale)` or `POST` because i had rejected edit on this question because of that reason only .

Comment: I had my edit committed. Sorry if you refered to `point of sale` :(

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at cUrl in PHP: http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

You can do POST requests with that from PHP.

Maybe this example helps: [http://wiki.uniformserver.com/index.php/PHP_cURL:*GET*%26_POST#Example_11_-_cURL_POST](http://wiki.uniformserver.com/index.php/PHP_cURL%3a_GET_&_POST#Example_11_-_cURL_POST)

Comment: Consider also using the Symfony buzz bundle: https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioBuzzBundle which is basically a wrapper over the php curl functionality.  Some find buzz easier to use than raw curl.

Comment: @Cerad how to do `POST` request in `buzzbundle`

Comment: It depends.  Some folks will read the documentation and follow the examples.  Others will pay someone else to do the research and write the code.